# Azure Create Alert via API

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Creating Alert via API in Azure.
Alert does get created but the Event Category field is showing as **all** instead of **Administrative**.

Alert i want to create is for Administrative Event Category but it is getting created for all Event Category.

I had used the same code earlier and it was working.

[Azure Alert ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fr08.jpg)

If i try to update anything via GUI it gives an error: Failed to update alert 'Testing'.The category field is missing in the condition..

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xksHG.jpg)

**PowerShell**

**Body to create Alert**

```
$Remediate = @" {
"id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/activityLogAlerts/Testing",
"type": "Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts",
"name": "Testing",
"location": "Global",
"kind": null,
"tags": {},
"properties": {
    "scopes": ["/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
    "condition": {
        "allOf": [{
            "field": "Category",
            "equals": "Administrative",
            "containsAny": null
        }, {
            "field": "operationName",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/write",
            "containsAny": null
        }]
    },
    "actions": {
        "actionGroups": [{
            "actionGroupId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/TestingAlertGRP",
            "webhookProperties": ""
        }]
    },
    "enabled": true,
    "description": "Alert created for Testing"
},
"identity": null
}

"@
```

**API**

```
$API = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.insights/activityLogAlerts/$Name`?api-version=2017-04-01"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $API -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $Token"} -Body $Remediate -ContentType 'application/json' | Out-Null
```

Comment: Could my reply solve your issue? If so, please mark it as answer. If not, let me know, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You must specify at least one (Administrative, Security, Service Health, Recommendation, Policy, Autoscale) of the preceding criteria in your alert. You may not create an alert that activates every time an event is created in the activity logs.

[image]

For more details, refer “[Create activity log alerts (Classic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts)”.

Answer (score 0):

> Alert does get created but the Event Category field is showing as all instead of Administrative.

Not to reproduce this issue, I check the request body, it should be fine.

> If i try to update anything via GUI it gives an error: Failed to update alert 'Testing'.The category field is missing in the condition

I have reproduced this issue when the `Event category` is `all`(I modify the category to `all` via the API mentioned below).

[image]

If you want to fix the issue, I recommend you to use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogalerts/createorupdate). Just click the `Try It` in the page and login your account. You could refer to the screenshot and my sample request body.

**My sample request body:**

```
{"location":"global","properties":{"scopes":["/subscriptions/xxxxxxx"],"description":"test","condition":{"allOf":[{"field":"category","equals":"Administrative"},{"field":"resourceType","equals":"Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"}]},"actions":{"actionGroups":[{"actionGroupId":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourcegroups/joywebapp/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/joyactiongroup","webhookProperties":{}}]},"enabled":true}}
```

**Request:**

[image]

[image]

**Check in the portal:**

[image]